# Codeigniter create custom custom config files

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and git for this project.

Is it possible to create custom config files for each different developer and between develop and production branch. Because between develop and master branch we have different values for the database login credentials and other variables.

What I hope to achieved is at the config.php in the config folder, have something like
$this->load->file('Developer_file')

where 'Developer_file' is the file for each different developer.

What I have now is just lumping all config variables in the config.php file in the config folder, just want to have  a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **[environments](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/environments.html)** are the way to go here. It is already built in CI so you won't need to make your own system.

I have a similar setup as yours I think: GIT+CI and multiple devs.

You can add as many as you want and easily create separate config files, such as database connections and paths. In your projects `index.php` you'll define the dev's or sites environments.

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

So you will have a config folder structure like this:

```
/application
    /config
        /development
        /other-dev
        /staging
        /production
```

Watch out if you use git that you don't include the `index.php` in your repo (or at least not with that name). You'll have to upload that one manually.

Comment: this looks good. so for the index.php i have to git ignore it then?

Comment: i'd recommend it yes. otherwise you'll keep overriding each others index files. Since they are the once defining which specific environment you are in.

Comment: You could always keep a copy of the index file in the repo under a different name. eg: ```index_copy.txt``` That way you can copy that file and rename it when you install your app in a different location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some think like this:

1. Add different config files to `config` folder.
2. Define in `index.php` some constant, something like this `define('DEVELOPER_TYPE', 'developer');`
3. Change `config/autoload.php`. Something like this:

   ```
   switch(DEVELOPER_TYPE){
       case 'developer':
           $autoload['config'] = array('developer_config');
           break;
       case 'tester':
           $autoload['config'] = array('tester_config');
           break;
   }
   ```